# Hide 'convert to comment' from the mod menu on deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, moderator-tools, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

♦ moderators can convert answers to comments. Converting a *deleted* answer to a comment is not possible; you'll get a message

> answer deleted; can't be converted to comment

This makes sense; converting an answer to a comment deletes it in the meantime so it's an extra safeguard against duplicate comments.

However, wouldn't it better to simply hide the 'convert to comment' option from the mod menu? It's something which is dynamically loaded based on the state of the post, so it shouldn't be too hard to filter this option out.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to see it grayed out, but kept in place. That would maintain muscle memory for the other actions.

Comment: That would work for me, but there are other options in the menu, e.g. 'show 1 deleted comment', which appear only when they're applicable. So much for muscle memory ...